How to change the time zone of logged events in Serilog?
I want to change the time zone in which Serilog logs events. By default, it uses the system's time zone, but I need to log events in a different time zone.I tried using CultureInfo with a different time zone, but that only changes the formatting of the date and time, not the time zone itself.
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.File(path: "Logs/logs-.txt",
                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Month,
                outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
            .CreateLogger();



Seems related to Serilog Timestamp @t is not in UTC time

I found a solution that worked for me.
It turns out I needed to create a custom class that inherits from ILogEventEnricher. This allowed me to add my own timestamp with the exact datetime format I needed.
Here's the code:
public class CustomDateFormatter : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        var now = DateTimeProvider.Now();
        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(propertyFactory.CreateProperty("customTimeStamp", now));
    }
}

and then
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.With(new CustomDateFormatter())
            .WriteTo.File(
                path: "Logs/logs-.txt",
                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Month,
                outputTemplate:"{customTimeStamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
            .CreateLogger();

DateTimeProvider:
public static class DateTimeProvider
{
    private static readonly TimeZoneInfo CetZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");

    public static DateTime Now()
    {
        var cetNow = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, CetZone);

        return cetNow;
    }
}


If you control the output format then you can use a ITextFormatter
    public class CustomLogLineFormatter(TimeZoneInfo timeZone) : ITextFormatter
    {
        private readonly TimeZoneInfo _timeZone = timeZone;

        public void Format(LogEvent logEvent, TextWriter output)
        {
            // Get the time of the log event as UTC
            var utcDatetimeOffset = logEvent.Timestamp.ToUniversalTime();

            // Convert the time of the log event to this._timezone
            var timeZoneDateTimeOffset = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcDatetimeOffset, _timeZone);

            // Format as ISO8601 with zone offset
            var isoFormat = timeZoneDateTimeOffset.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz");

            output.Write($"[{isoFormat}] ");
            logEvent.RenderMessage(output);
            output.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Timezone to use in the logger. For valid id strings see:
        //    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones
        var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("New Zealand Standard Time");

        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console(new CustomLogLineFormatter(tzi))
            .CreateLogger();

        logger.Information("My log message");
    }

